# JQuery-UI tabs work for old versions of JQuery and JQuery-UI, but not for new versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hnyqxxq/), I have linked to `JQuery 1.9.1` and `JQuery UI 1.9.2`. The tabs work perfectly.

In [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/xy3jcrz2/1/), I have lined to `JQuery Edge` (I am assuming it to be `3.1.1` version, because that's the *latest* version I found and downloaded) and `JQuery 1.8.9` (I have downloaded `1.12.1` version though).

The weird thing is that in the second JSFiddle, the tabs don't work. They don't appear as tabs but as lists.

The problem is that I can not link to online versions, as my program must work offline as well. I need JQuery and JQuery-UI versions whose tabs work and which can be downloaded.

The question is that how do I fix this? Why is this happening? **Can you suggest me versions of JQuery and JQuery-UI with which the tabs would work *and* which are available for download as well?**

Comment: Please tell me why you downvoted. I read the instructions. I can't see what is wrong with my question.

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI & jQuery compatibility:

- 1.12.1 (Stable, for jQuery1.7+)
- 1.11.4 (Legacy, for jQuery1.6+)
- 1.10.4 (Legacy, for jQuery1.6+)
- 1.9.2 (Legacy, for jQuery1.6+)

**[SOURCE](http://jqueryui.com/download/)**